# Repeat a table for each row of another table

Tags: formulas, excel-online

I have this table in Microsoft Excel Online:

| Col A (Month) | Col B (Date) |
| --- | --- |
| January | 1/1/2023 |
| January | 1/2/2023 |
| January | 1/3/2023 |

And I have another table:

| Col C (Dept.) | Col D (KPI) |
| --- | --- |
| Dep1 | KPI1 |
| Dep1 | KPI2 |
| Dep2 | KPI3 |

I want to repeat the first table for each item from the second table to be like:

| Col E (Month) | Col F (Date) | Col G (Dept.) | Col H (KPI) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | 1/1/2023 | Dep1 | KPI1 |
| January | 1/2/2023 | Dep1 | KPI1 |
| January | 1/3/2023 | Dep1 | KPI1 |
| January | 1/1/2023 | Dep1 | KPI2 |
| January | 1/2/2023 | Dep1 | KPI2 |
| January | 1/3/2023 | Dep1 | KPI2 |
| January | 1/1/2023 | Dep3 | KPI3 |
| January | 1/2/2023 | Dep3 | KPI3 |
| January | 1/3/2023 | Dep3 | KPI3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted [the question](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/10rlyrg/repeat_a_table_for_each_row_of_another_table_in/) on Reddit's r/excel, and the following [answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/10rlyrg/comment/j6xd8wl/) by u/wjhladik worked:

> ```
> =LET(
>   x,BYROW(A2:A4,LAMBDA(row,TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,row))),
>   y,TRANSPOSE(BYROW(A10:A12,LAMBDA(row,TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,row)))),
>   TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("!",TRUE,x&","&y),",","!"))
> ```
>
> x joins the first table by row using ","
>
> y joins the second table by row using "," and transposes it
>
> x&","&y combines the two tables into a matrix so each element of the matrix is (t1a,t1b,t2a,t2b)
>
> then we join all those together into a single string separated by "!"
>
> finally we split that string with "!" indicating rows and "," indicating columns